# @Async annotation in Spring boot stops working after a while

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

**Version Details:**

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
```

I have spring boot application where am configuring the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` as shown below

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("workExecutor")
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor matchmakerThreadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(1);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(1000);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setKeepAliveSeconds(10000);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("Work-TPE-");
    return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
}
```

Here is my implementation on `@Async`

```
@Async("workExecutor")
public void sendRequest(String value) {
    try {
        .....
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("An exception occured while sending following request  : {} ", e);
    }
}
```

Things works fine intially, but intermittently `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` gets stops working in the middle and  get killed silently :(

Leads to the restart of my application frequently.

Could someone guide on this?

Comment: `catch (Exception e)`, how about telling us what the stacktrace is

Comment: Am trying to catch generic `Exception` so that I will not miss anything out. Basically in a gist the logic contains the HTTP Rest call to a service. @ScaryWombat